# How to solve Fredholm integral equation of the second kind? ($f(x) - \lambda\int\limits_0^1 9xtf(t) dt = ax^2 - 4x^2$)

Tags: functional-analysis, integral-equations

I have an equation : $\ f(x) - \lambda\int\limits_0^1 9xtf(t) dt = ax^2 - 4x^2\ $ in $\ L_2[0,1]\ $ space.

And I want to understand how to solve it, not just obtain an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this particular equation, it is simple. Differentiate both sides of the equation with respect to $x$:
$$
   f^\prime(x) = 2 (a-4) x + \lambda \int_0^1 9 t f(t) \mathrm{d} t
$$
Since the integral is independent of $x$, the solution is a quadratic $f(x) = (a-4) x^2 + b x + c$. Substituting into the original equation we get a linear system of equations for $b$ and $c$:
$$
  (a-4) x^2 + b x + c - \lambda x \int_0^1 9 t f(t) \mathrm{d} t = (a-4) x^2
$$
Since $\int_0^1 9 f(t) \mathrm{d} t = \frac{9}{4} a+ 3b+ \frac{9}{2} c - 9$, we get the system:
$$
  c = 0 \qquad b (1-3 \lambda) - \frac{9}{4} \lambda \left( 2 c + a -4\right) = 0
$$
Therefore we obtain:
$$
  f(x) = (a-4) x \left( x -\frac{9}{4} \frac{\lambda}{3 \lambda - 1}  \right)
$$

Comment: Can you recomend a good book on these theme?

Comment: @PhilippG.Sinicyn [The book](http://www.amazon.com/First-Course-Integral-Equations/dp/9810231016) "First course on integral equations" by Wazwaz may be a good start.

Comment: How to solve this if $\lambda = \frac{1}{3}$

Comment: @PhilippG.Sinicyn Come back to equations for polynomial coefficients. They would say $c=0$, $a=4$ and would leave $b$ free, which is to say, equation will have no solutions if $a\not=4$, and if $a=4$, then $f(x) = b*x$ would be a solution

Answer (score -1):

If the Kernel (what is in along with the unknown function in the integral) is polynomial, then it is easy to solve. In this case, multiply your equation by *x* and integrate between 0 and 1, then obtain the value of ∫tf(t)dt and replace in the original equation to get the solution.